# Rotate Function doesn't work fine On sending each time or once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send 10 deg each time to rotate it right side or left side but it never rotate. And I want to rotate it in each browser. What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script>
function rotate(deg){
        var degree = deg;
        document.getElementById("image").rotate({ angle:0+degree,animateTo:+degree,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo }); 
}
</script>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Rotate" onClick="rotate('10')">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("#image")` and don't forget to include the `jQuery` library to your code, since the scripts you're using are based on it. See the snippet below.

Also, in order for the rotate button to work every time, I moved your `degree` variable declaration outside the function, so it wouldn't reset every time the function is called. Then I add the value `deg` to it each time the function is called, thereby increasing the angle accordingly.

```js
var degree = 0;
function rotate(deg){
        degree += deg;
        $("#image").rotate({ angle:0+degree,animateTo:+degree,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Rotate" onClick="rotate(10)">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
```

Comment: Yes you have done well but Why it never move forward again and again when i hit the rotate button it have to do rotate again and again with adding of 10 degree.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I repositioned your variable declaration to make it work multiple times. Hope this helps :)

Comment: If I would have $ sign issue in conflicting what to do then because it never works in the website and it works on separate page?

Comment: It returns with NaN when i call alert(degree);

Comment: Yes, parseInt sometimes gives odd results. I noticed you don't really need to use a string parameter in the first place when caling function `rotate()`, so I changed your button's onClick from `rotate('10')` to simply `rotate(10)` and removed the parseInt altogether. See if my updated snippet works.